# Android: App crashing when displaying font picker style dialog

Tags: android, android-typeface

I have 53 fonts installed on my device. Scrolling from top to bottom in this list about 20 times results in the app crashing. When using a recycled view, I've added setting the typeface to null and manually calling System.gc() with the same result.

List adapter:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;
        //despite the gc, this function evenually causes out-of-memory
        if (convertView != null && convertView instanceof TextView) {
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
            textView.setTypeface(null);
            System.gc();
        } else
            textView = new TextView(context);

        textView.setText(fontNames[position]);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile(fontPaths[position]));
        textView.setTextSize(32);

        return textView;
    }


11-16 16:17:50.080 5402-5402/com.global.client A/libc: new failed to allocate 32768 bytes
11-16 16:17:50.080 5402-5402/com.global.client A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5402 (al.mobileclient)
```

SDK 15 and 21, LGG2 device. Anything else I can do to make this more likely to succeed?

Comment: You don't have to call `System.gc()` manually. System **always** calls garbage collector before throwing the `OOM`. Also, for making your list view more efficient (at least 25%) use holder pattern: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder .

Comment: @Shubham he is using a recycler view i'm assuming since he mentioned that in the question, recycler view has viewholder pattern build into it

Comment: Yes, neither textView.setTypeface(null);or System.gc(); is in production code.